# How do I debug single unit test with pydev?

Tags: pydev

When using pydev, ctrl+f9 opens a convenient window that lets me choose which unit test to run in the current file. Is there a debug version of the same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best one I've found is press f9, run test then immediately cancel and press f11 which launches last configuration in debug mode

Comment: After all this time, I could not find something better. I do ctrl+F9 then F11

Answer (score 8):

press Ctrl + F9 to initiate unit tests. At the next dialog which allows you to select the test, hold shift when you press enter, this will run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Tests can also be run in debug mode by: `right clicking file -> Debug As -> Python unit-test` I have found this to be less finicky that the Ctrl + F9...Shift approach which will runs normally (rather than in debug mode) if shift is held too long or not long enough when selecting tests to run.